# БПФ. Как получить точность в 1Гц быстрее чем за секунду?

Tags: аудио, fft, фурье, verilog

Добрый день.
Заранее прошу прощения, если буду плавать в сабже -- в универе не преподавали преобразование Фурье.
В общем, я пытаюсь написать гитарный тюнер на verilog. Имеется аудио-кодек, который оцифровывает звук с частотами дискретизации 8-96кГц. Есть блок БПФ, в котором можно настроить сколько точек он будет принимать. Мне нужно получить точность в 1Гц (или лучше) в диапазоне частот 60-700Гц. При этом желательно иметь минимальную задержку. Насколько я понимаю, точность зависит от частоты дискретизации и числа точек в БПФ: error = fs/num_points. Получается, чтобы иметь погрешность <= 1Гц, необходимо взять точек больше чем частота дискретизации, т.е. потратить от одной секунды только на выборку.
Можно ли ускорить этот процесс? И да, мне известно про принцип неопределенности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ходе экспериментов с матлабом, пришел к выводу, что можно брать меньшее число точек из аудиопотока, а остальное заполнять нулями -- вместо точности от этого пострадает амплитуда в спектре. Во всяком случае, такой результат наблюдается у аудио где преобладает одна нота и ее обертона.